# Where are cookies and local storage stored for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I read that:

> cookies are small files which are located on a user’s computer

and

> localStorage is a way to store data on the client’s computer

But where are these actually stored? How can I find Chrome's cookie files and local storage on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS and browser, but lets you have Chrome browser and Windows 7... then you can find cookies in:

```
C:\Users\USERNEME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Note that cookies are stored in SQLite database file format - hence why you have only one file in your computer.

As for the Local Storage - you can find it there too:

[image: 0]